# MonoDevelop Code Wrapping C#

Tags: mono, monodevelop

With MonoDevelop C#, when I press the Format Code button (CTRL+SHIFT+F) the IDE will take a multi line statement and create a long single one. For lambda and LINQ statements, this can be counter productive.

I am looking for a way to have the IDE format the code, but if a command is on seperate lines, to leave it on seperate lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should get filed as a bug in MonoDevelop, not as a question on StackOverflow.